# Selecting a string corresponding to the nth number of elements in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary

Im coming accross a very annoying problem here. my goal in this challenge is to return an array, holding the names of the 5 most active buyers by volume. stockSymbols is holding those names, while the total bought is successfully worked out and placed into the totalBought array. I then tried to work out the top 5 largest and put their names into totalSold and return.

I am an absolute novice at c++, so I am aware this way of doing things is incorrect. It also wont compile, its throwing memory errors all over the place (starting at or around the if(biggest[0] < totalBought[i])) line.

If any of you know a better way of making this work successfully I would be grateful for your input, or if you know how to make this way work that would also be very useful. I would really love to find the most efficient way (in terms of speed) to compute this though.

Many thanks.

```
string* Analyser::topFiveBuyers()
{
    // Your code
string* totalSold;
totalSold = new string[5];

    string stockSymbols[] = {"W Buffet", "P Lynch", "G Soros", "J Neff", "Hargreaves Lansdown",
        "Sippdeal", "Saga", "Halifax", "iWeb", "Alliance Trust", "Clubfinance", "Lloyds TSB", "Saxo" };

    int totalBought[13];

    for(int i = 0; i < nTransactions; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 13; j++)
        {
            if(transArray[i].buyerName == stockSymbols[j])
            {
                totalBought[j] += transArray[i].numShares;
            }
        }
    }

    int biggest[] = {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1};

    for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
    {
        if(biggest[0] < totalBought[i])
        {
            biggest[4] = biggest[3];
            biggest[3] = biggest[2];
            biggest[2] = biggest[1];
            biggest[1] = biggest[0];
            biggest[0] = totalBought[i];
            totalSold[0] = stockSymbols[i];
        }
        else if(biggest[1] < totalBought[i])
        {
            biggest[4] = biggest[3];
            biggest[3] = biggest[2];
            biggest[2] = biggest[1];
            biggest[1] = totalBought[i];
            totalSold[1] = stockSymbols[i];
        }
        else if(biggest[2] < totalBought[i])
        {
            biggest[4] = biggest[3];
            biggest[3] = biggest[2];
            biggest[2] = totalBought[i];
            totalSold[2] = stockSymbols[i];
        }
        else if(biggest[3] < totalBought[i])
        {
            biggest[4] = biggest[3];
            biggest[3] = totalBought[i];
            totalSold[3] = stockSymbols[i];
        }
        else if(biggest[4] < totalBought[i])
        {
            biggest[4] = totalBought[i];
            totalSold[4] = stockSymbols[i];
        }
    }

    return totalSold;
}
```

Comment: Start with this is **undefined behavior**. You're returning the address of a local scope auto variable.

Comment: That was a massive mistake on my part, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Anything off-limits for this? because honestly a little setup and [`std::partial_sort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort) (or even just [`std::sort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)) would pretty much seal this deal.

Comment: Speed without sacrificing too much memory usage is key but right now il settle for getting it working. The only problem is when sorting the totalBought I lose track of who has bought what (as stockSymbols[0] is the buyer for totalBought[0]) Meaning I wouldnt be able to return the correct result.

Comment: yeah, its hard to picture as-is, since I would use a std::map<string,int> to store the transaction accumulations, then use it as a source for the final sorted data. That probably sounded like a foreign language, and I apologize for that.

Comment: Ive been looking at maps right now but I am not sure how to implement it, I can see that it would work as it would essentially be a linked array rather than the two I have used in that case. So many of the resources I am looking at really do talk in a foreign language though. Would you happen to know of some simple tutorial type resources I could look at to assist me here?

Comment: A `map<string,int>` would be ideal for tracking the accumulated counts, since you would just index into it with the transaction buyer name, and bump the accumulated total by the transaction share count. The harder part is sorting the results on share-count afterward. I could post a sample of how to do it, but if you're not even familiar with maps, it would probably give you dizzy spells. =P

Comment: I'll not clutter the answers here with the type of algorithm I'm talking about, but you can [see it here](http://ideone.com/RHvmN1) if you're interested. I had to fake the transaction structure since I've no idea what yours actually is, and passed the transactions in as a parameter list since I don't have access to the Analyzer class, but you can get the idea. Regardless, I'll take a look at your code and see if there is something obvious that is breaking your algorithm.

Comment: I honestly understood very little of that but thank you for the effort put in, that is definitely something I will be pursuing further. To fix the program so far I have deleted all those nasty if statements, and placed the totalBought and stockSymbols into a pair. Will edit the OP to reflect that, but I cant seem to sort an int/string pair, researching how to do it. Thanks again for all of your help though.

Comment: You may understand the answer I'm about to post instead. It doesn't use C++11 specifics, and does what I think you want using a map and multimap in concert. Regardless, glad you at least found it entertaining =P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest a combination map and multi map for achieving what you want. I took the liberty of changing the result of the function to be a vector of strings, which it honestly should be:

```
std::vector<string> Analyzer::topFiveBuyers()
{
    typedef map<string, int> xact_map;
    xact_map xacts;
    for (int i=0;i<nTransactions;++i)
        xacts[transArray[i].buyerName] += transArray[i].numShares;

    // enumerate the map, beginning to end, throwing all elements
    //  into a multimap keyed by transaction count rather than name.
    //  note this considers an element "less" (and therefore at the
    //  beginning of the sort order) if the share count is *greater*.

    typedef multimap<int, string, std::greater<int>> highest_map;
    highest_map highest;
    for (xact_map::const_iterator it=xacts.begin(); it != xacts.end(); ++it)
        highest.insert(highest_map::value_type(it->second, it->first));

    // now just peel off the top five elements from the multimap.
    vector<string> results;
    int n=0;
    for (highest_map::const_iterator it=highest.begin(); 
         it != highest.end() && n<5; ++it,++n)
    {
        results.push_back(it->second);
    }

    return results;
}
```

Comment: That is a much more understandable answer for me, thank you very much :3. Still couldnt understand a couple of bits in there but my friendly search engine filled in my blanks.

Comment: @AaronBoreland I somewhat figured. I sure hope it works =P Since I don't have access to your class, I was kinda flying blind, but it looks like it should. So long as you understand how the map and multimap standard containers operate, it should be pretty straight-forward to understand.